# python: importing modules with incorrect import statements => unexhaustive info from resulting ImportError

Tags: python, import, importerror

I have a funny problem I'd like to ask you guys ('n gals) about.

I'm importing some module A that is importing some non-existent module B. Of course this will result in an ImportError.

This is what A.py looks like

```
import B
```

Now let's import A

```
>>> import A
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/tmp/importtest/A.py", line 1, in <module>
  import B
ImportError: No module named B
```

Alright, on to the problem. How can I know if this ImportError results from importing A or from some corrupt import inside A *without* looking at the error's string representation.

The difference is that either A is not there or does have incorrect import statements.

Hope you can help me out...

Cheers bb

Answer (score 2):

There is the [`imp`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) module in the standard lib, so you could do:

```
>>> import imp
>>> imp.find_module('collections')
(<_io.TextIOWrapper name=4 encoding='utf-8'>, 'C:\\Program Files\\Python31\\lib\\collections.py', ('.py', 'U', 1))
>>> imp.find_module('col')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    imp.find_module('col')
ImportError: No module named col
```

which raises `ImportError` when module is not found. As it's not trying to import that module it's completely independent on whether `ImportError` will be raised by that particular module.

And of course there's a `imp.load_module` to actually load that module.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the back-trace, which can be examined in the code.

However, why do you want to find out - either way A isn't going to work.

Comment: this is for some kind of plugin-system where user-coded modules are imported at runtime (depending on some user-input) and may exist but be incorrectly implemented by the user... for example by importing wrong modules...

Comment: addition: i want to know if A _does_ exist in the first place